# spark Scala for loop inside again for loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a count which is a list as below

```
   My data in count as below
   (Focus,37)
   (Test,26)
```

and my code is as below.

```
         for (i <- count ) {
              for(x <- i {
                 if(x == "Focus"){
                     Focus_cnt=i(x) }
                        else if(x == "Test"){
                           Test_cnt=i(x) }
                           else {
            pass
        }
    }
}
```

The error i am facing is at line -  for(x <- i   and the error is  i: (Any, Any)

Any better way to get counts in spark Scala.

Comment: What does the have to do with Spark. Also can you please fix your code ?

Comment: If your count is a collection of `Tuple` as shown, why do you expect the `for( x <- i)` loop to work ?

Comment: Can you post your complete code here ?

Comment: Need suggestion on the code.

Comment: @Srinivas, The code is already there.

Comment: I mean where spark code , by looking above code its only scala code.

Comment: What is `count` ?

Comment: are you taking counts into variables from spark dataframe ?

Comment: @Srinivas From dataframe i am getting the list and then i am doing for loop to get the counts.   val counts = df.groupBy("status").agg(count("status").as("cnt")).rdd.map(x => (x(0), x(1))).collect() and the storing the count in different val's

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this ? let me know if i understood wrongly. 
In this i am applying filter & taking counts.

```
scala> Seq(("fa","fb","fc",5,"fe","ff","Focus"),("fba","fbb","fbc",16,"bd","be","Focus"),("fba","fbb","fbc",54,"bd","be","Focus"),("fca","fcb","fcc",135,"fcd","fef","Focus"),("a","b","c",5,"e","f","Test"),("aa","ba","ca",56,"ea","fa","Test"),("ab","cb","cc",35,"de","df","Test")).toDF("a","b","c","d","e","f","status")
res29: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: string ... 5 more fields]

scala> val df = Seq(("fa","fb","fc",5,"fe","ff","Focus"),("fba","fbb","fbc",16,"bd","be","Focus"),("fba","fbb","fbc",54,"bd","be","Focus"),("fca","fcb","fcc",135,"fcd","fef","Focus"),("a","b","c",5,"e","f","Test"),("aa","ba","ca",56,"ea","fa","Test"),("ab","cb","cc",35,"de","df","Test")).toDF("a","b","c","d","e","f","status")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: string ... 5 more fields]

scala> val newDF = df.groupBy("status").agg(count("status").as("count"))
newDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [status: string, count: bigint]

scala> val focus_cnt = newDF.filter($"status" === "Focus").select("count").map(_.getAs[Long](0)).head
focus_cnt: Long = 4

scala> val test_cnt  = newDF.filter($"status" === "Test").select("count").map(_.getAs[Long](0)).head
test_cnt: Long = 3
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct . But i am not able to convert to dataframe. Since i am pulling the count from dataframe and writing to a list.

Comment: why are you writing to a list ? can't you do same using spark dataframe or can you show schema of your complete dataframe ?

Comment: Schema is as below :  root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- c: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d: long (nullable = true)
 |-- e: string (nullable = true)
 |-- f: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: string (nullable = true)                                                                                        and i am getting only status and count from the dataframe and writing into different variables.

Comment: I have updated above answer based on given schema. check now ?

Comment: .head is not recoginzed.So removed it. After that i am facing error at map(_.getAs[Long](0)) and the error is x$1: <error>.

Comment: please find my code    val focus_cnt = newDF.filter(col("status") === "Focus").select("count").map(_.getAs[Long](0)).

Comment: my local its working , what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: The version of spark 2.3

Comment: even spark 2.3 version its working .. can you post your full code ?

Comment: I mean in my eclipse its showing error so can't build jar and the same exact code i have given and with .head i am facing the below error. ◾Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
◾not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Long])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.

Comment: can you try same using spark-shell ?

Comment: In shell it will work. But i am looking in eclipse to get my code compiled and run the jar.

Comment: I am not sure, may be some problem with your eclipse.

Comment: Is there a way to get the counts like below :                                                                     
  val newDF = df.groupBy("status").count().select("status", col("count").alias("cnt"))

Comment: just try only this - df.groupBy("status").count

Comment: any idea how to loop the list and get the counts rather than a dataframe?